# How to fill a percentage of a glyphicon [Bootstrap 3]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Hi there i have 5 star rating system and i would like to make it so that i can add say 4.3 stars rather than just 4. How would i do this? My current code is listed below:

```
<center>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:#BBD41C"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:#BBD41C"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:#BBD41C"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" style="color:#BBD41C"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</center>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could overlap 2 absolute positioned divs. Each would contain all 5 stars. Then the top div could have an overflow:hidden div in it, where you set the width equal to a percentage (based on the rating).

Here is a codepen that I put together that illustrates it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBWwX The code snippets are copied below for reference and includes a little extra than what is needed, for the purpose of the demo.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flt_left">
    <form id="star_form">
      <label for="star_input">Stars:</label>
      <input type="text" id="star_input" />
      <button id="setStars">Set Rating</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="flt_left">
    <div id="star_box">
      <div class="star_limiter">
        <div class="longbar">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="star_bg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <p id="rating_data"></p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.container{
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
}
p{
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.flt_left{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  /*min-width: 250px;*/
}
#star_box,
.star_bg{
  color: #BBD41C;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 4px 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
}
.glyphicon{
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#star_box{
  z-index: 2;
}
.star_bg{
  color: #555;
}
#star_box .star_limiter{
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function setWidth(perc){
  $('#star_box .star_limiter').css('width',perc+'%');
}
function starToPercent(amt,outof){
  if(typeof outof == 'undefined') outof = 5;
  var percent = Math.round(amt*100/outof);
  if(percent > 100) percent = 100;
  $('#rating_data').text(amt+' of '+outof+' stars, or '+percent+'%');
  setWidth(percent);
}
function setRating(){
  var input = parseFloat($('#star_input').val());
  var num_stars = $('#star_box .star_limiter .glyphicon-star').length;


  if(!isNaN(input)) starToPercent(input, num_stars);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var star_width = $('#star_box').width();
  var star_height = $('#star_box').height();
  $('#star_box').css('width',star_width+'px');
  $('#star_box .star_limiter').css('height',star_height+'px');
  $('#star_box .longbar').css('width',star_width+'px');
  
  $('#setStars').click(setRating);
  $('#star_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setRating();
  });
});
```

**Notes:**
The overlapped stars don't look great, since you see a bit of the color of the background stars around the edges. So, it looks better if you get rid of the background stars and just use a solid color. It also is less noticeable the more you match the color.

I set the CSS of the glyphicons to display:table-cell to prevent them from wrapping and to position them closer together. More space between the stars creates less accurate results on floats.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could make this more flexible and accurate, if you used an `overflow:hidden` div on each star. So, a rating of 3.4 would give you 5 divs with 3 set to 100%, 1 to 40%, and 1 to 0% width.

Comment: You sir, is da bomb! Thanks +1

Answer (score 4):

You can't use multiple colors on an icon font, so what you ask isn't possible. You could use a partial background fill, but that doesn't seem very desirable.

If you switch to [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io) you would at least have access to [half-star](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star-half/) symbols.

Answer (score 3):

I found this works, the major drawback being that you need to style specific classes based on the font size:

HTML:

```
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half-star"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.half-star {
        width:5px; // Roughly half the font size
        overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

While these answers are both correct (regarding multiple colors) and long and perhaps too exact (overlapping divs, which uses pixels to move things), I found a great hack just now involving the :after selector.

Basically, if you know what the background color is going to be, you can just cover half (or whatever percentage you need) of a character this way:

HTML:

```
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half-star"></span>`
```

CSS:

```
   .half-star {
     letter-spacing: -0.5em;
       &:after {
       position: absolute;
       content: "";
       left: 0.5em;
       width: 0.5em;
       height: 1em;
       background-color: $body-bg;
     }
   }
```

First, I set the letter-spacing to half the font's default, which aligns the following text, stars, or other elements correctly.  Then, I create an absolutely positioned block of `$body-bg` half the width of the star and half-way over the star (this is for a 4.5 star rating).  You can change that decimal to match your desired rating.

You cannot change the color of the glyph, and it would take much more hacking to add a different color or glyph over the first (think the same way as I showed but from the other direction) but it could be done without any Javascript and purely with HTML and CSS this way.

Answer (score 1):

Font-awesome has a ready star-system solution:
Look at "Star Ratings (inspired by CSS Tricks)"
[in their website](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

Comment: There's not a single word about percentage of a star

Comment: At the bottom of the page there is a link to this source: http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/